# Как вы привязываете события?

Tags: javascript

Какой на ваш взгляд, самый лучший способ привязки событий?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если jquery я обычно привязываю так:

```
 var el = $("#dontCare");
 el.on('eventName', function(e){});
```

Именно так делаю по очень простой причине - если в коде используются пользовательские события ( а у меня они используются всегда ) это помогает избежать каши в коде и привести все к единому виду. Т.е.

```
 el.on('mySuperPuperEvent', function(e){})
 // на глаз не особо отличается от
 el.on('click', function(e){}); // например обработчика клика

 // тогда как, например
 el.mousemove(function(e){})
 // и 
 el.on("mySuperPuperEvent", function(e){});
 // как видите получается кашко...
```

Ну и еще я такой подходи использую потому-что привык точно так-же писать обработчики nodeJS

В Prototype все примерно так-же:

```
 el.observe("eventName", function(e){});
```

Если речь о нативном JS - я не пишу на нем под старые браузеры, соответственно использую привязку по w3c стандарту

```
 el.addEventListener("event",function(){e}, false);
```

А самый лучший тот которые лучше читается. В том смысле что не так важно как именно вы это будете делать, важно чтобы это все было реализовано в едином стиле.

При небольшом JS коде это вообще не принципиально, если же код большой - нужно просто выбрать единый стиль и везде его придерживаться.

Answer (score 6):

Через джиквери, естественно.

обычный:

```
$('selector').event(function(){...});
```

или

```
$('selector').bind('event',function(){...});//Для более легкого преобразования в динамический.
```

динамический:

```
$('selector').live('event',function(){...});
```

Answer (score 4):

Кроссбраузерно.

```
function ae(e,t,f){if(e.addEventListener){e.addEventListener(t,f,false);}else if(e.attachEvent){e.attachEvent('on'+t,function(){f.apply(e)});}else{e['on'+t]=f;}return e;}
ae(document.getElementById('id'), 'click', function(){alert(this.innerHTML);});
```

Comment: function ae(e,t,f)// Wassup?... Зачем же ТАК сокращать?

Comment: Сейчас придет Expert и исправит на:
function ae(e,t,f)// Что здесь происходит? Зачем же сокращать название функции до двухбуквенного, если это задача программы по сокращению и оптимизации загрузки?

Comment: Буквы по поджимали а точки с запятой нет.. На вскидку вижу 5 точек с запятыми которые можно убрать!

Ах да - еще пробелы!!!

Comment: Просто я когда-то взял с javascript.ru функцию привязки событий и сократил ее, чтобы торчала одной строкой в инклюде и не отсвечивала. =)

Comment: Да я так и понял, просто выглядит "немного" не читабельно =)

Answer (score 1):

Кроссбраузерно)

```
function $(selector) { return document.getElementById(selector); }
function Selector()
{
    $('mydiv').onclick = function()
    {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
document.onreadystatechange = Selector;
```